# Dart lang, manipulating server returned JSON data in the client

Tags: dart

I want to check the user log in parameters, and if the parameters accepted, I want the server to send back to the client both the name and roles of the user, to be saved in the SeassonStorage for further usages.

my server side code is:

```dart
....
....   
  var users = <Map>[];
  var logged = <Map>[];   
....
....
 .then((_) {  
                  for (var user in users) 
                      if(_theData['userName']==user['Alias'] && _theData['password']==user['Password'])
                  {
                    userFound=true;;
                    logged.add({
                              "Alias":user['Alias'],
                              "Roles": user['Roles']
                            });                     
                  }    
                })
      .then((_) {
                if(userFound == true)
                  res.write(JSON.encode(logged));
                else
                  res.write('sorry, unknown loggin');
                res.close();  
      });
```

in the client side, I've:

```dart
....
....
if(request.responseText != 'sorry, unknown loggen'){
    server_msg.innerHtml='Welcome';
    print(request.responseText);
    print(JSON.decode(request.responseText));
    var FonixLogin = JSON.decode(request.responseText);       
      print(FonixLogin['Alias']);
      print(FonixLogin['Roles']);
    Storage sessionStorage = window.sessionStorage;
      sessionStorage['FonixAlias'] = FonixLogin['Alias'];
      sessionStorage['FonixRoles'] = FonixLogin['Roles'];
....
```

the output I get is:

```dart
    [{"Alias":"Admin","Roles":"admin"}]
    [{Alias: Admin, Roles: admin}]
    Exception: Illegal argument(s): Alias login.dart:66login_Element.onData
```

Why mistake I made here, so that the returned data is not saved properly in the

Comment: Which line is line 66 for `login.dart`?

Comment: print(FonixLogin['Alias']);

Comment: Not to criticize your exploration of Dart, but I should point out that storing the user identifier and role information in the client introduces a security issue: The session information can be modified on the client side allowing an attacker to masquerade as any user and granting themselves any role. Web authentication or single-sign-on protocols generally store an opaque security session identifier in the browser session that maps to a user security session on the server side where roles etc. are stored. This identifier is designed to be impossibly difficult to construct or guess.

Comment: Thanks @ArgentiApparatus for your note, can you provide some links so I learn the implementation of what you mentioned using DART!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FonixLogin` is a `List` and you access it like a `Map`.

Try `print(FonixLogin[0]['Alias']);`